# Power Automate Cloud - Sharepoint check if a filename without extension already exist in a folder

Tags: power-automate

I have a worklfow that needs to check to see if an email attachment has already been uploaded to a specific SharePoint folder. I need it to check for the filename without extension.

I have tried a few different things , without success.

Currently I am using the Get Files (properties only) action.
*I then have a filter array, filtered to see if the Get Files dynamic value "Name" is equal to the Outlook Attachment Name (trimmed to remove the extension)
*Then I am taking the length of the filter array to see if it equals 0

If it equals 0, it will create the file in the folder
If it is not equal to 0, it means the file already exists and it will not create the file in the folder

[image]

Comment: Can you tell us why what you’re doing isn’t working?

Comment: When I run a test on this flow, it doesn't work as expected. It's not properly recognizing that the file name already exists in the Sharepoint folder (regardless of the file extension).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out another way to make this work. I replaced the SharePoint Get Files (properties only) action with the SharePoint List Files action.

[image]